# Extracting Text Between boundaries by applying logical parameters

Tags: excel, powerquery, delimiter, m

First I think this is a complicated question to follow. Please see the Steps of my M code which I think will make it clearer.

So I am trying to achieve the following:

[image]

The idea is any text in the input box can be limited to relevant sections using the parameters table If the Text in the parameters box is Contained in the Text being searched. For me, at least the question is more complicated than it first appears. If required /interested Please see my explanation below:

**Desired Output**
Fundamentally I want a way of filtering the Input text, using the parameters box such that each line returned is **contained** only within the relevant sections of start1-End1, Start2-End2.

Ideally, you can use any part of the text to set the limits. So I could say Everything between SECTION1-2, and between lines 2 and 5. will returns lines 2-5.

Or you could say Everything between SECTION 1-3, lines 4-8. Will return lines 4-8. Note you could even say SECTION1-3, Lines 4 -SECTION 4 which would return lines 4 up to 14.

Finally you could even overlap sections and These should still be captured separately and the lines where overlap occurs should repeat in the output.

M Code:

**Parameters:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start1", type text}, {"End1", type text}, {"Start2", type text}, {"End2", type text}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"Start1", "End1"}),
    #"Duplicated Column1" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Filled Down", "Start1", "Start1 - Copy"),
    #"Duplicated Column2" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Column1", "End1", "End1 - Copy"),
    #"Duplicated Column3" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Column2", "Start2", "Start2 - Copy"),
    #"Duplicated Column4" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Duplicated Column3", "End2", "End2 - Copy"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Duplicated Column4", "Custom", each "X"),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Start1", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("+++", QuoteStyle.None),"Start1"),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Merged Columns", "End1", "End1 - Copy.1"),
    #"Merged Columns3" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"Start1", "End1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Search1"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Columns3", "Custom", each "X"),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1", each "X"),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Start2", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("+++", QuoteStyle.None),"Start2"),
    #"Merged Columns4" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns1",{"End2", "Custom.1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("+++", QuoteStyle.None),"End2"),
    #"Merged Columns2" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Merged Columns4",{"Start2", "End2", "End1 - Copy.1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Search2"),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Columns2", "Custom", each Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([Search1], ","), Text.Split([Search2], ",")})),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Start1 - Copy", "End1 - Copy","Start2 - Copy","End2 - Copy","Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Search1", "Search2"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Search1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"+++"}, QuoteStyle.None, true), {"Search1", "Filter1"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Search2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"+++"}, QuoteStyle.None, true), {"Search2", "Filter2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Search1", type text}, {"Filter1", type text}, {"Search2", type text}, {"Filter2", type text}}),
    #"Filled Down1" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type1",{"Search1"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filled Down1",{{"Filter1", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Sorted Rows",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Filter1", "Search2", "Filter2"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

**Text:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TextToSearch"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Text", type text}}),
    Search1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Search1",  (x) => Table.SelectRows(Parameters, each Text.Contains(x[Text],[Search1], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
    #"Expanded Search1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Search1, "Search1", {"Search1", "Filter1"}, {"Search1", "Filter1"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Expanded Search1",{"Search1", "Filter1"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Filter1] = "X")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Text", "Search1"}),
    Search2 = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Search2",  (x) => Table.SelectRows(Parameters, each Text.Contains(x[Search1],[Search1], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) and Text.Contains(x[Text],[Search2], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(Search2,{"Text", "Search2"}),
    #"Expanded Search2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Search2", {"Start1 - Copy", "End1 - Copy", "Start2 - Copy", "End2 - Copy", "Search2", "Filter2"}, {"Start1 - Copy", "End1 - Copy", "Start2 - Copy", "End2 - Copy", "Search2.1", "Filter2"}),
    #"Filled Down1" = Table.FillDown(#"Expanded Search2",{"Search2.1", "Filter2"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down1", each ([Filter2] = "X")),
    #"Removed Other Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Start1 - Copy", "End1 - Copy", "Start2 - Copy", "End2 - Copy", "Text"}),
    #"Filled Down2" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Other Columns2",{"Start1 - Copy", "End1 - Copy", "Start2 - Copy", "End2 - Copy", "Text"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filled Down2",{{"Start1 - Copy", "Start1"}, {"End1 - Copy", "End1"}, {"Start2 - Copy", "Start2"}, {"End2 - Copy", "End2"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Real Example:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsrLaUgt0KCLvUgQQctfMtFe057l?e=AkbeP3

Comment: See the help on how to create a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is with partial matches.

[image]

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8kjNUdJRCnZ1DvH091MwArJzMvNSFQxhDBOlWJ1oJSAPJgBXYgqWQdYJYxvDTTGAswxRVJsiqTaFmwxXbWSkFBsLAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Start1 = _t, End1 = _t, Start2 = _t, End2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start1", type text}, {"End1", type text}, {"Start2", type text}, {"End2", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Start1", "End1"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Replaced Value",{"Start1", "End1"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Custom", each let 
input = Input[Text],
s1 = List.PositionOf(input, List.FindText(input,[Start1]){0}),   
e1 = List.PositionOf(input, List.FindText(input,[End1]){0}),
r1 = if s1=e1 then  List.Range(input,s1) else List.Range(input,s1,e1-s1+1),
s2 = List.PositionOf(r1, List.FindText(input,[Start2]){0}),
e2 = List.PositionOf(r1, List.FindText(input,[End2]){0}),
r2 = List.Range(r1,s2,e2-s2+1)

in r2),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom")
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: Not sure what ive changed but this appears to be working now as expected on a text file

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCnZ1DvH091MwVNKBs42A7JzMvFSwIJhhohSrE60E5MEE4EpMwTLIOmFsY7gpBnCWIYpqUyTVpnCT4aqNjJRiYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Start1 = _t, End1 = _t, Start2 = _t, End2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start1", type text}, {"End1", type text}, {"Start2", type text}, {"End2", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Start1", "End1"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Replaced Value",{"Start1", "End1"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Custom", each let 
input = Input[Text],
s1 = List.PositionOf(input, [Start1]),
e1 = List.PositionOf(input, [End1]),
r1 = if s1=e1 then  List.Range(input,s1) else List.Range(input,s1,e1-s1+1),
s2 = List.PositionOf(r1, [Start2]),
e2 = List.PositionOf(r1, [End2]),
r2 = List.Range(r1,s2,e2-s2+1)

in r2),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom")
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: Hi David, hm I can only get this to work for this example. If I change SECTION 1 to Say Hello and match this in the parameters (Start1 = Hello) I get `The Count arguments is out of range error`

Comment: I have just tried it and it works fine for me. There is no error checking or case sensitivity so you need to account for that. You might have an errant space or something like that too. It works on the sample data so if you have other data it doesn't work on, please post a full example.

Comment: Just looking into it. I thinkIf I cant solve,  I may share with you the file on one drive to take a look at if that is okay

Comment: Just post your sample data and I will see why it is failing

Comment: Right okay, I have got it to work using Hello. But I notice that its very specific as you say. For Exampe if `Start1 = Hel` and `Text = Hello`, I can cause the Count error. Any way to have an equivalent to Text.contains?

Comment: I didn't realise you wanted partial matches. I'll post a separate answer in a minute.

Comment: Apologies, The Text example I thought would make things easier. Let me post real sample data.

Comment: I have posted a partial match answer.

Comment: Its better! But I am running into issues with my real example. I have posted a File here if you would like to look: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsrLaUgt0KCLvUgQQctfMtFe057l?e=AkbeP3

Comment: I can also post a sample but post its getting long. let me know

Comment: I've looked at your file. The reason it fails is that "2.3. Other hazards" doesn't sit between the indexes of Start1 and End1.

Comment: the way it is coded, Start2 and End2 must be inside of Start1 and End1. I'm obviously not understanding your requirements so might be best to let someone else have a crack. I can delete my answer if you need me to.

Comment: Ah my mistake. But even if I make End1 =  SECTION 3 I get the same error.

Comment: your answer is certainly useful as it deals with the overlap issue well. I Just need to keep looking at it to understand why it fails in certain cases.

Comment: End2 sits outside Start1 and End1.

Comment: Although that explains some, there are examples where Start2, End2 sit inside and Start1 End1 and still fails. Will look into it. Its close though!